# Making subtraction, division and multiplication filtering your data per interval between days

Tags: mysql

**Hi**, my **MYSQL** data base contains the table called `new-sell` with the following columns `registeredDay` and `productFinalPrice` they show total registered purchase value and the date that entry was made.

```
|=====================================|
|  productFinalPrice | registeredDay  |
|=====================================|
|     600,00 | 2017-09-19 18:45:16    |
|     435,50 | 2017-09-18 18:45:16    |
|     817,60 | 2017-09-17 18:45:16    |
|     176,00 | 2017-09-16 18:45:16    |
|     600,00 | 2017-09-15 18:45:16    |
|     600,00 | 2017-09-14 18:45:16    |
|     600,00 | 2017-09-13 18:45:16    |
|     842,10 | 2017-09-20 18:45:16    |
|     415,20 | 2017-09-21 18:45:16    |
|     230,45 | 2017-09-22 18:45:16    |
|     400,00 | 2017-09-20 18:45:16    |
|     375,00 | 2017-09-20 18:45:16    |
=======================================
```

**My idea is as follows**;

Get `productFinalPrice` in **two queries** at **separate intervals** in `BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 day) AND CURDATE()` and `BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -2 day) AND CURDATE()` the idea is that these two results of `DATE_ADD` are **available** for calculations of **subtraction**, **division** and **multiplication**.

The data **received** according to the **two intervals** of days listed **above** should be treated in this way **subtracted**, **divided** and **multiplied**.

*Example:*

**First interval 1 day** - `2017-09-20` result in total `R$ 1617,10` and **second interval 2 day** `2017-09-19` result in total `R$ 2217,10` **remembering** that these **data** are **variable** and should **change** **according** to the **day** that this **information** is being **requested**:

**2217,10 - 1617,10 = 600 ÷ 1617,10 = 0,37 × 100 = `37,10%`**

Could **someone** give you an **idea** how to **fit** this **calculation** into a **query mysql**?

Was able to **get** the **input values** `R$ 1617,10` and `R$ 2217,10` **through** these **consultations**.

```
SELECT productFinalPrice FROM new_sell WHERE registeredDay BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 day) AND CURDATE()

SELECT productFinalPrice FROM new_sell WHERE registeredDay BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -2 day) AND CURDATE()
```

**It is** at this **point** it would be **possible** to fit to **fitting** the **subtraction**, **division**, and **multiplication** model **along** with the **interval day filtering** for **exibity result** using `BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 day) AND CURDATE()`?

Sorry, for the length of the question but want to offer maxim of information about my question.

I did not find anything on how to join calculations with time interval filter if anyone could help me i'll be grateful :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?  I used with your sample data and it works.  Let me know pls.

```
SELECT   PRICE_T / (PRICE_T2-PRICE_T) * 100 AS PERC
FROM (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN RN=1 THEN PRICE_I2 ELSE 0 END) AS PRICE_T
           , SUM(PRICE_I2) AS PRICE_T2
      FROM (SELECT CAST(registeredDay AS DATE) AS DDATE
            , SUM(productFinalPrice) AS PRICE_I2
            , @RN:=@RN+1 AS RN
            FROM new_sell 
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT @RN:=0) X
            WHERE registeredDay BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -2 day) AND CURDATE()
            GROUP BY CAST(registeredDay AS DATE)
            ORDER BY CAST(registeredDay AS DATE)
           ) B
    ) C;
```

Output:

```
PERC
37,1057513914657
```

Comment: yesss, worked perfectly, thank you for your help can take me one last doubt it would be possible for me to filter this final percentage for only `37,10` or some form of visually formatting this result?

Comment: see ROUND() function